# Chart Data shows it's never updated through my setState variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I have a popup dialog where I get a bunch of values from the user and then get a response after making an API request. I put an inline conditional rendering on the dialog box as it should only render once chart data is updated from the response. However, the dialog never appears even if console.log shows the data is updated. I tried to use useEffect() with many functions but it did not work. Any idea how to refresh the data again?

Edit: Added only relevant code

```
const [barGraphData, setBarGraphData] = useState([]);

const funcSetBarGraphData = (newBarGraphData) => {
        setBarGraphData(newBarGraphData);
    };

const sendChartData = async () => {
        let bar_response = await axios.post(
            "http://localhost:8080/h2h-backend/bardata",
            bar_data,
            {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
        ).then(res=>{
            const resData = res.data;
            const resSubstring = "[" + resData.substring(
                resData.indexOf("[") + 1, 
                resData.indexOf("]")
            ) + "]";
            const resJson = JSON.parse(resSubstring);  
            console.log(typeof resJson, resJson);
            funcSetBarGraphData(barGraphData);
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err);
        });

        chartClickOpen();
};
```

Returning popup dialog with charts when button is clicked:

```
<StyledBottomButton onClick={sendChartData}>Submit</StyledBottomButton>
                {barGraphData.length > 0 && <Dialog
                    fullScreen
                    open={openChart}
                    onClose={chartClickClose}
                    TransitionComponent={Transition}
                >
                    <AppBar sx={{ position: 'relative' }}>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <Typography sx={{ ml: 2, flex: 1 }} variant="h6" component="div">
                            Analytics View
                            </Typography>
                            <IconButton 
                            edge="start"
                            color="inherit"
                            onClick={chartClickClose}
                            aria-label="close"
                            >
                                <CloseIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </AppBar>
                    <Grid container spacing={2}>
                        <Grid item xs={8} sx={{ pt: 2 }}>
                            <BarChart width={730} height={250} data={barGraphData}>
                                <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                                <XAxis dataKey="business_name" />
                                <YAxis />
                                <Tooltip />
                                <Legend />
                                <Bar dataKey="num_of_customers" fill="#8884d8" />
                                <Bar dataKey="sum_total_amount" fill="#82ca9d" />
                            </BarChart>
                            {/* <Bar options={set_bar.bar_options} data={set_bar.bar_data} redraw={true}/> */}
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={4} sx={{ pt: 2 }}>
                            {/* <Pie data={data2} /> */}
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid> 
                </Dialog>}
                <StyledBottomButton onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</StyledBottomButton>
```

Comment: can you point out the exact part of the code that is not working

Comment: Yes, it's this part which I am using to render the popup after I have all data `{barGraphData.length > 0 && <Dialog` but it does not render even after I have got my data from the API response in the state variable

Comment: And how do you check that `barGraphData.length` is actually larger than 0?

Comment: I thought that when the data in `barGraphData` gets updated from the API, it's not empty anymore with items inside so it must be of length > 0. Please feel free to correct me since I am very new to React